# Selecting a class using properties as a selector - PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

So, I'm wanting to select a  PHP object via its property, sorta like how you'd select an HTML element in JS through the `$('.element[selector=false]')` kinda thing.

How would I go about selecting the object of class `Business` Which has the name of `The Night's Watch`, without knowing its variable name?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific: where is this `Business` object stored? I think at first glance that your application is not properly designed: you should be able to select object and store them depending on the criterion of your choice.

Comment: This depends on where your objects are stored. From where do you want to search for this?

Comment: Paste the code, then we can help you out might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so difficult as it would seem

```
// this will be array of all variables 
$vars = get_defined_vars();
foreach(array_keys($vars) as $v)
   if (gettype($$v) == 'object' and           
       get_class($$v) == 'Business'  and      // get_class returns class name
       $$v->name == 'The Night's Watch')      // test property
      echo 'Variable you find is ' . $v;
```

Comment: That's very strange to have some data stored in a variable developer does not know...

Comment: i don't know, maybe he write an debugger

Answer (score 0):

For find property name of the string The Night's Watch  .. please do below code...

```
$string_to_find = "The Night's Watch";
//suppose $obj is the object of the class Business 
foreach ($obj as $property => $value) {
      if ($value == $string_to_find) {
          // You found the string
          echo $property;
          echo $value;
      }
  }
```